# How to set placeholder as value to a date-picker

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am using Vue3 with options api. the question is not about formatting the date

Given the code posted in StackBlitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-kasehp?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue,src%2FApp.vue), the default date that  initially set is `dd.mm.yyyy`. I would like to know how to set the date to that default format. In other words, when the user does specific action, I want to display `dd.mm.yyyy`.
For the sake of testing, I tried the following:

```
methods: {
    onDatePickerTimeSeriesAgoToChanged(evt) {
        const msg = JSON.stringify({ msg: verboseTag + 'onDatePickerTimeSeriesAgoToChanged():', evt });
        console.log(msg);
        this.compPropsVModelDatePickerTimeSeriesAgoTo = evt
        this.compPropsVModelDatePickerTimeSeriesAgoTo = undefined//<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    },
},
```

but that did not achieve what I am looking for. How to set the date to `dd.mm.yyyy`?

**Note**:

the question is not about formatting the date. also,
the format of the placeholder does not matter whether it is dd.mm.yyyy or any other thing. the point is how can i display that placeholder? i want to display the placeholder when specific action occurs. is that ever possible please?

in other words, on occurance of a specific condition, i want to change the date-picker from, for example, 01-12-2021 to dd.mm.yyyy

Comment: Can you clarify your requirement? Are you saying you selected `04/10/2023` from the input component, but the console.log had `2023-10-04` but you want `04/10/2023` instead?

Comment: @rachitiitr what i want to achieve is to display the following characters in the date picker.i do not want to display any numbers , i want to display the following characters dd.mm.yyyy, is it clearer now

Comment: So it's not about formatting the date, but displaying the string " dd.mm.yyyy" as a placeholder, i see

Comment: @Amrmsmb default placeholder for `<input type="date" />` is determined by the user's browser and is usually displayed in the format set by the user's system preferences. Do you want to just change this placeholder value from `dd/mm/yyyy` to `dd.mm.yyyy`? What if user selects a date then, would you want the selected input date to also follow the `dd.mm.yyyy` notation?

Comment: @rachitiitr thanks for your comment. the format of the placeholder does not matter whether it is dd.mm.yyyy or any other thing. the point is how can i display that placeholder? i want to display the placeholder when specific action occurs. is that ever possible please?

Comment: @Amrmsmb Changing placeholder of `input` element of type `date` is not supported.  

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#:~:text=For%20example%20size%20and%20placeholder%20might%20not%20work

Comment: @rachitiitr i do not want to change it. on occurance of specific condition, i want to change the date-picker from, for example, 01-12-2021 to dd.mm.yyyy

Comment: @Amrmsmb what's that specific condition? Default is `dd/mm/yyyy` lets avoid `dd.mm.yyyy` to avoid confusion. Now user selects date to `01/12/2021`, what do you want to do now? You want to reset to `dd/mm/yyyy` again? That will make user think their selection didn't work. Your use case is still not clear.

Comment: @rachitiitr the case is, the user selects some configurations, selecting a date is one of them. if the user select some specific configuration i want to reset the date-picker so it displays the original place holder dd/mm/yyyy or whatever the placeholder will be..is it clearer now?

Comment: @Amrmsmb I see, I have answered it below, works fine now. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77236065/19093452

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `v-model` here. Refer below, have made the fix.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-v7xkzh?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue,src%2FApp.vue

In your template,

```
<input
      id="idDatePickerTimeSeriesAgoTo"
      type="date"
      :max="maxDateToSelect"
      v-model="compPropsVModelDatePickerTimeSeriesAgoTo"
      @input="
        $emit(
          'update:compPropsVModelDatePickerTimeSeriesAgoTo',
          $event.target.value
        )
      "
      :disabled="isDatePickerTimeSeriesAgoToDisabled"
      @change="onDatePickerTimeSeriesAgoToChanged($event.target.value)"
    />
```

In your scripts,

```
data() {
    return {
      maxDateToSelect: new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0],
      compPropsVModelDatePickerTimeSeriesAgoTo: '',
    };
  },
methods: {
    onDatePickerTimeSeriesAgoToChanged(evt) {
      const msg = JSON.stringify({
        msg: verboseTag + 'onDatePickerTimeSeriesAgoToChanged():',
        evt,
      });
      console.log(msg);
      this.compPropsVModelDatePickerTimeSeriesAgoTo = evt;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.compPropsVModelDatePickerTimeSeriesAgoTo = '';
      }, 3000);
    },
  },
```

I added the code to let user change the date, show the selected date for 3 seconds, and then reset back to `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Answer (score 1):

Vue cobtains a so called v-[model](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html). It allows for two-way binding. If you edit the input the value changes. If you change the value, the displayed form changes.
Take a look a at the [vue-playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9j81qwzAQhF9lEQE7kNp344SW0kNvPfVS9WDidSrQH9LKF+N37yoOxoSQm7QzO9/sJN68r8aEohFtPAflCSJS8idplfEuEEwQcIAZhuAMFGwtVuk9RXLm0/pEN7mqN7Ocy2YAac/ORgKDMXYXhGOOLIs/1NoVe2nbekEzlD+ExuuOkH8A7ZYxvhjXoz5KcUuSAuoTTNOaPM85bU0QB3HX58GdPQ7K4ldwPpY/xZXw3Wmu/svVFvHDKMpi8j3HNneeZ/VVBucXQDPmjVx+XZdikV6vNpZ2yKTyAecAOxzRUkVduCCfkqf7Zb9m1Pbo+R9ZkqZn):

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import CustomInput from './CustomInput.vue'
  
const message = ref('hello')
</script>

<template>
  <CustomInput v-model="message" /> {{ message }}
</template>
```

On load we set a value but when you input anything it also triggers a change. So you could define an event that changes the value and thus the Input.

---

Alternatively use [vue-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker), which has a `cleared`-event you could emit when needed.

Comment: please read the `note` section i added to the question

Comment: @Amrmsmb i edited my answer accoringly, tell me if it works